# ZMQ failing when sending larger chunks of data over LAN

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq

well basically i have a single master system and 3 slave systems . I have used Request/Response phase to send the content to 3 of my client systems  , since it inherently solves my problem of data splitting . After sending the content to 3 of my client systems , i close the socket which  was responsible to REQ/REP topolgy and created another bunch of sockets which pairs with individual slave systems inorder to receive the content from all 3 system. I ran the whole code in localhost i didnt have any problem and everything went smooth , even when i tried to send 40MB data sets from one of the client system to master system .

The problem is when i tried implementing this over LAN in my lab

1. The REQ/REP phase runs smoothly , so basically all the client systems fetch the data sets to work on.
2. The indivudal PAIR with client kinda fails when i try processing large sets of data (like the 40MB , which i kinda dont consider larger since i loaded the content in dictionary and size of the dictionary object came to 24MB ) it kinda gets choked and for some reason doesnt process.

I have no idea on why its behaving differently over the LAN than from my system.

The systems that i use in LAN are AMD dual core 64bit with 2GB RAM ( all 4 systems)

Incase if your interested to run the code :

Master System code : http://codepad.org/5uVCEb42

Salve1 : http://codepad.org/LNmi9vu2

Slave2: http://codepad.org/0vmEAJYc  ( this one takes in 40MB content from a file and  finally passes to Master system)

Slave3: http://codepad.org/d565lgiv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PAIR sockets don't automatically reconnect, so they're not recommended for LAN use.

Comment: REQ-REP. When you need to send a big chunk of data REQuest permission. The REPly will tell you to go ahead, and then you can REQuest a confirmation. The recipient then REPlies that it all came through OK.

Comment: Make that first REQ send a byte count to expect, and a checksum.